# How to correctly initialise a Bean in the main method of a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, initialization

I have the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class StartupConfig {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.debug("Start up config initialized.");
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerService schedulerService() {

        return new SchedulerService();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to load the `schedulerService` bean from the applications `main` method. Something like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.crm.config.StartupConfig;
import com.crm.service.SchedulerService;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(StartupConfig.class);
        context.refresh();

        SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);

        SchedulerService schedulerService = (SchedulerService) context.getBean("schedulerService");
        schedulerService.start();
    }
}
```

The schedulerService class has an `Autowired` dependency:

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class SchedulerService {

        @Autowired
        private SchedulerTriggerJpaDao schedulerTriggerJpaDao;
        ...
```

Here is the definition of `SchedulerTriggerJpaDao`:

```
package com.crm.dao;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.crm.entity.SchedulerTrigger;

@Transactional
public interface SchedulerTriggerJpaDao extends JpaRepository<SchedulerTrigger, Integer> {

    public Collection<SchedulerTrigger> findByEnabledTrueAndDeletedFalse();

}
```

When I run up the application I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'schedulerService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'schedulerTriggerJpaDao'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.crm.dao.SchedulerTriggerJpaDao'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)

What do I need to change to correctly initialise the schedulerService bean so it can also initialise the `schedulerTriggerJpaDao` dependency?

Comment: how did you define `schedulerTriggerJpaDao`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SchedulerTriggerJpaDao class has the following annotation

```
@Repository
```

then it should be recognised as a bean.

Comment: I have added the `@Repository` annotation to the `SchedulerTriggerJpaDao` interface. But I still get the same error on startup.

Comment: You could try to explicitly add your `com.crm.dao` package by using the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SchedulerTriggerJpaDao` is just an interface. You need

1. either provide a Dao implementation yourself and annotate it with `@Component`
   (FYI `@Repository` and `@Service` automatically mark class as component)
2. or use some framework that will generate a Dao implementation for you based on your interface. E.g. Spring Data JPA (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a `new` instance of the SchedulerService, which is not managed by spring. You are annotating the  class as a `@Service` but spring is only managing the one injected by `@Inject` and/or `@Autowire`.